# Missing log lines when writing to cloudwatch from ECS Docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, docker-container, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

(Docker container on AWS-ECS exits before all the logs are printed to CloudWatch Logs)
Why are some streams of a CloudWatch Logs Group incomplete (i.e., the Fargate Docker Container exits successfully but the logs stop being updated abruptly)? Seeing this intermittently, in almost all log groups, however, not on every log stream/task run. I'm running on version 1.3.0

---

Description:

A `Dockerfile` runs node.js or Python scripts using the `CMD` command.

**These are not servers/long-running processes, and my use case requires the containers to exit when the task completes.**

Sample Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:6
WORKDIR /path/to/app/
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD [ "node", "run-this-script.js" ]
```

All the logs are printed correctly to my terminal's stdout/stderr when this command is run on the terminal locally with `docker run`.

To run these as ECS Tasks on Fargate, the log driver for is set as `awslogs` from a CloudFormation Template.

```
...
LogConfiguration:
   LogDriver: 'awslogs'
     Options:
        awslogs-group: !Sub '/ecs/ecs-tasks-${TaskName}'
        awslogs-region: !Ref AWS::Region
        awslogs-stream-prefix: ecs
...
```

Seeing that sometimes the cloduwatch logs output is incomplete, I have run tests and checked every limit from [CW Logs Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch_limits_cwl.html) and am certain the problem is not there.

I initially thought this is an issue with node js exiting asynchronously before `console.log()` is flushed, or that the process is exiting too soon, but the same problem occurs when i use a different language as well - which makes me believe this is not an issue with the code, but rather with cloudwatch specifically. 

***Inducing delays in the code by adding a sleep timer has not worked for me***.

It's possible that since the docker container exits immediately after the task is completed, the logs don't get enough time to be written over to CWLogs, but there must be a way to ensure that this doesn't happen?

sample logs:
incomplete stream:

```
{ "message": "configs to run", "data": {"dailyConfigs":"filename.json"]}}
running for filename
```

completed log stream:

```
{ "message": "configs to run", "data": {"dailyConfigs":"filename.json"]}}
running for filename

stdout: entered query_script
... <more log lines>
stderr:
real 0m23.394s
user 0m0.008s
sys 0m0.004s
(node:1) DeprecationWarning: PG.end is deprecated - please see the upgrade guide at https://node-postgres.com/guides/upgrading
```

Comment: What happens if you throw logs in system itself rather than Cloudwatch? Do you then get full logs?

Comment: @deosha yes, i get the complete logs if it's on the system

Comment: Can you post Cloudwatch logs as well as full logs?

Comment: @deosha updated the question to include, but content of the actual logs has nothing to do with the error, since i'm seeing this across a range of different tasks.

Comment: Cannot really tell for the CloudWatch Logging Driver, but I can recommend to look at the alternative https://collectord.io, which is based on the json-files logging driver and forwards from the files. Collectord holds the references to the files, and forwards them to the CloudWatch till the end always.

Comment: The underlying AWS bug now appears to be fixed, so there is no need to implement a workaround to receive all the logs. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE: This now appears to be [fixed](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=907178#907178), so there is no need to implement the workaround described below**

---

I've seen the same behaviour when using ECS Fargate containers to run Python scripts - and had the same resulting frustration!

I think it's due to CloudWatch Logs Agent publishing log events in batches:

> **How are log events batched?**
>
> A batch becomes full and is published when any of the following conditions are met:
>
> 1. The `buffer_duration` amount of time has passed since the first log event was added.
> 2. Less than `batch_size` of log events have been accumulated but adding the new log event exceeds the `batch_size`.
> 3. The number of log events has reached `batch_count`.
> 4. Log events from the batch don't span more than 24 hours, but adding the new log event exceeds the 24 hours constraint.
>
> *(Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html)*

So a possible explanation is that log events are buffered by the agent but not yet published when the ECS task is stopped. (And if so, that seems like an ECS issue - any AWS ECS engineers willing to give their perspective on this...?)

There doesn't seem to be a direct way to ensure the logs are published, but it does suggest one could wait at least `buffer_duration` seconds (by default, 5 seconds), and any prior logs should be published.

With a bit of testing that I'll describe below, here's a workaround I landed on. A shell script `run_then_wait.sh` wraps the command to trigger the Python script, to add a sleep after the script completes.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine
ADD run_then_wait.sh .
ADD main.py .

# The original command
# ENTRYPOINT ["python", "main.py"]

# To run the original command and then wait
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "run_then_wait.sh", "python", "main.py"]
```

**run_then_wait.sh**

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Wait 10 seconds on exit: twice the `buffer_duration` default of 5 seconds
trap 'echo "Waiting for logs to flush to CloudWatch Logs..."; sleep 10' EXIT

# Run the given command
"$@"
```

**main.py**

```py
import logging
import time

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # After testing some random values, had most luck to induce the
    # issue by sleeping 9 seconds here; would occur ~30% of the time
    time.sleep(9)
    logger.info("Hello world")
```

Hopefully the approach can be adapted to your situation. You could also implement the sleep inside your script, but it can be trickier to ensure it happens regardless of how it terminates.

It's hard to prove that the proposed explanation is accurate, so I used the above code to test whether the workaround was effective. The test was the original command vs. with `run_then_wait.sh`, 30 runs each. The results were that the issue was observed 30% of the time, vs 0% of the time, respectively. Hope this is similarly effective for you!

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer, just looked at the forums page, it says - "this should now be resolved for any new tasks launched". Does this mean i need to redeploy all old tasks to get this fix into effect?

Answer (score 5):

Just contacted AWS support about this issue and here is their response:

> ...
>
> Based on that case, I can see that this occurs for containers in a
>   Fargate Task that exit quickly after outputting to stdout/stderr. It
>   seems to be related to how the awslogs driver works, and how Docker in
>   Fargate communicates to the CW endpoint.
>
> Looking at our internal tickets for the same, I can see that our
>   service team are still working to get a permanent resolution for this
>   reported bug. Unfortunately, there is no ETA shared for when the fix
>   will be deployed. However, I've taken this opportunity to add this
>   case to the internal ticket to inform the team of the similar and try
>   to expedite the process
>
> In the meantime, this can be avoided by extending the lifetime of the
>   exiting container by adding a delay (~>10 seconds) between the logging
>   output of the application and the exit of the process (exit of the
>   container).
>
> ...

**Update**:
Contacted AWS around August 1st, 2019, they say this issue has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this as well. It must be an ECS bug?

My workaround (Python 3.7):

```py
import atexit
from time import sleep

atexit.register(finalizer)

def finalizer():
    logger.info("All tasks have finished. Exiting.")
    # Workaround:
    # Fargate will exit and final batch of CloudWatch logs will be lost
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: i did try to induce a an explicit sleep, but it doesn't seem to help in my case - i added multiple waits within the script that launches other scripts in the container but logs don't print even then. My guess is that it's a log flush issue rather than a time thing

Comment: same,  added sleeps along the script, and still get half of the log

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with flushing logs to `CloudWatch`.

Following [asavoy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55359669/8912534) answer I switched from exec form to shell form of the `ENTRYPOINT` and added a 10 sec sleep at the end.

Before:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

After:

```
ENTRYPOINT java -jar /app.jar; sleep 10
```